# IF condition not working correctly

Tags: php

When I enter correct email and incorrect password I see "email do not exist!"
Why :(?

```
$emailnumrow = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email' "));

if($emailnumrow['.$email.'] >= 1){
 } else {echo 'email do not exist!';}
```

Comment: There's no such thing as an "if loop".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mysql_num_rows` returns `int` not an `array`.It should be

```
if($emailnumrow >= 1){
    ....
}else {
    echo 'email do not exist!';
}
```

Comment: Yes it works but i also have to change "*" into "email" in the first line.
Thank you

Comment: Also can use `"SELECT COUNT(email) FROM users WHERE email = $email"`. It returns `int type`.